# How to get the current page to enable social sharing

Tags: dxa, java

I am using the share Component provided with the example site. Here `request.getURl` resolves to the view page and not the actual url shown on the browser.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2website%2FWEB-INF%2FViews%2FCore%2FPage%2FGeneralPage.jsp

I want to share http://website/scoreboard/image-library

How can I get the current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DXA .NET we use `var pageUrl = Url.Encode(Request.Url.ToString());` (as you can see in https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Site/Areas/Core/Views/Entity/SocialSharing.cshtml), and in DXA Java that is:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("pageUrl", URLEncoder.encode(request.getAttribute(com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.RequestAttributeNames.SOCIALSHARE_URL).toString(), "UTF-8")); %>
```

(as you can see in https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/develop/dxa-coremodule/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/SocialSharing.jsp)